# How do I cycle memory efficient through the data of an ObjectBox db?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, objectbox

I am working on a Kotlin app in Android. I am using the ObjectBox interface for Kotlin to store up to 40 million data point objects. I want to upload and delete them from the db. I do this by retrieving lists of 100000 objects and uploading them, then deleting them from the db one list at a time.
With a fast network connection this creates the problem that the upload jobs work faster than the garbage collector clears the already uploaded objects from the ram.
I got this information from looking at the following log which comes up more than once a second.

> 2021-01-13 16:58:04.280 27936-27951/project I/e.project : Background young concurrent copying GC freed 175472(7966KB) AllocSpace objects, 10(1292KB) LOS objects, 25% free, 23MB/31MB, paused 1.295ms total 169.984ms

The upload is slowed significantly after a short amount of time, and regularly other memory errors pop up.

My understanding is that me querying and creating hundreds of thousands of objects into the memory only to upload them once and then discard them is very inefficient. But I was not yet able to find a better solution.

My ideas were:

1. Reuse the same 100.000 objects each iteration. So having only one list of data objects and after uploading them to fill the data of the next 100.000 entries from the db into the already existing objects. This way they would not have to be cleared by GC until after all data was uploaded.
   This would require a method to save the result of a query into a existing object/list of objects. I was not able to find this in the ObjectBox documentation.
2. Read the data as some kind of stream from the db and not represent them as objects at all during the upload. I was also not able to find this functionality in Objectbox.

Do you know of ObjectBox functionality enabling one of these approaches?
Do you know of a different approach to solve this problem?

I currently query the data using

> return sensorDataBox.query { }.find(offset = 0, limit = 100000)

Previously i was relying on

> sensorDataBox.query { }.findLazy()

but with 40 million + Objects in the box, even lazy lists were to large to retrieve all objects at once. And there is no limit parameter for querying lazy lists. So I had to revert to .find(offset, limit).

If you need me to provide more information please ask for it!

Comment: How do you currently get a batch of 100k objects? Some code would help to answer this.

Comment: E.g. if you use a query to get a batch, using a lazy list may already help: https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#lazy-loading-results